# onActivityResult user cancels the activity

Tags: android, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

I have a activity call for getting image

```
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
```

On my onActivityResult I want to handle the scenario if the user cancels the operation in between.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {

            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            if (selectedImagePath != null) {
                 //do something
           }
            else
                Log.i("At the","selectedimagenull");
            }

        else
            Log.i("At the","SELECT PICTURENULL");
    }
}
```

But if the user cancels the operation nowhere am getting information. I've tried to debug but its not catching anywhere. What am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Can you not check for `resultCode == RESULT_CANCELLED`?

Comment: even if `RESULT_CANCELLED` is not returned by the picture editor you are calling, anything that is not `RESULT_OK` could be construed as a cancel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {

            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            String selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            if (selectedImagePath != null) {
                 //do something
           }
            else
                Log.i("At the","selectedimagenull");
            }

        else
            Log.i("At the","SELECT PICTURENULL");
    }
  else
  Log.i("At the","result not ok");  // User cancelled the activity
}
```